# Is grace in the following sentence from Cosmos a noun or a verb?

Tags: grammar

> dThere seemed to be no way in which atoms and molecules could somehow spontaneously fall together to create organisms of such awesome complexity and subtle functioning **as grace every region of the Earth**.

Sagan, Carl. Cosmos

"... as grace every region of the Earth."
What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

**Grace** in this sentence is a verb. The meaning is:

> As adorn every region of the Earth.

Meaning 1 in Wiktionary:

> to grace - To adorn; to decorate; to embellish and dignify.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Then, what is the subject of grace?

Comment: @Cosmos - what would be your guess?

Comment: Atoms and molecules? Organisms?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the construction of as + verb. Could you kindly give me a sample sentence? Thank you very much for your help.